# Why does ITextsharp throw Time Out Exception on this Debug Function the first time?

Tags: c#, itext, immediate-window

I spend a lot of time tweaking tables for a PDF I am putting together, so rather than wait until the whole report is finished, download it, open it, scroll down to relevant section... I put together the following debug function:

```
        public static void PreviewItextObject(PdfPTable table, PageStyle pageStyle)
        {
            using (PdfWriterChunk writerChunk = new PdfWriterChunk(pageStyle))
            {
                writerChunk.Document.NewPage();                    
                writerChunk.Document.Add(table);
                PreviewDocument(writerChunk.Document, writerChunk.memoryStream);
            }
        }
        public static void PreviewDocument(Document doc, MemoryStream ms)
        {
            doc.Close(); // have to close doc before embedding PDF
            var data = ms.ToArray();
            var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
            filename += ".pdf";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
        }
```

where my PDFWriterChunk class looks like this:

```
        public PdfWriterChunk(PageStyle pageStyle)
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var margin = GetMarginFromStyle(pageStyle);


            Document = new Document(pageStyle == PageStyle.LandScape ? PageSize.A4.Rotate() : PageSize.A4,
                margin.Left, margin.Right, margin.Top,
                margin.Bottom);
            Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, memoryStream);
            Writer.SetPdfVersion(PDF_VERSION);
            Writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
            Writer.SetFullCompression();

            PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, Document.PageSize.Height, 0.75f);

            Document.Open();

            PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, Writer);
            Writer.SetOpenAction(action);
      }
```

For myself to call from the immediate window. However what's really frustrating is when I do call it from the immediate window, *nearly* every first time I get the following exception, which takes a long time to throw:

> An unhandled exception of type 'iTextSharp.text.DocumentException' occurred in itextsharp.dll
>   Additional information: The operation has timed out

As soon as I ignore that error and run it again, it works!

So clearly something is causing a wait or lock of some kind on the document.add, that leads to a long wait that leads to the exception. But i'm not sure what, anyone have any ideas how to avoid it? it always happens in the add, the new page seems fine. I always call it at the point the code is about to add it to the real document, which works also fine on a normal run.

Comment: Oddly if i take a lot of time writing out the function in the immediate window (rather then hitting up and running it again) it seems to work, but a thread sleep(1500) doesn't seem to help

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Eventually the document.Add throws the exception, what's interesting is how it gets stuck there for so long, when usually it takes no time at all , it must get into a race time muddle

Comment: Can you retrieve a stack trace of the exception?